# Convert List of key-value pairs in each row of RDD to single key-value in each row

Tags: scala, apache-spark, rdd

I have an RDD as

```
List((a,b),(b,c))
List((d,e))
```

How can I get it as

```
(a,b)
(b,c)
(d,e)
```

I have tried RDD.flatMap(x => x), this doesn’t work because there is a list of key value pairs and not just a list of values.

Answer (score 0):

`rdd.flatMap(identity)` will convert `RDD[List[(String, String)]]` to `RDD[(String, String)]`.

```
scala> val rdd = sc.parallelize(List(List(("a","b"),("b","c")), List(("d","e"))))
...
rdd: org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD[List[(String, String)]] = ParallelCollectionRDD[2] at parallelize at <console>:13
scala> rdd.flatMap(identity)
res2: org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD[(String, String)] = MapPartitionsRDD[3] at flatMap at <console>:14
scala> res2.collect()
...
res3: Array[(String, String)] = Array((a,b), (b,c), (d,e))
```

This would work like that for any `RDD[List[T]]`, regardless the shape of `T`.
Could help more if you shared a bit more info on what you try to do.